# Why i have array [] option as consturctor invoke?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class for example GooglePlayConnection. When I create object of this class without variable initialization (just to invoke method) **new GooglePlayConnection()** IDEA suggest to me 2 options: like default empty constructor () and .. array []? What does it mean?

[image]

I don't have any constructors in these classes.

Comment: It means that without context, the compiler doesn't know whether you want to create a single instance of your class or an array of it.

Comment: its a good idea to post actual class definition in answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

> ...and .. array []? What does it mean?

It's to create a `GooglePlayConnection` *array*:

```
GooglePlayConnection[] connections = new GooglePlayConnection[10];
connections[0] = new GooglePlayConnection(/*...*/);
// ...
```

or

```
GooglePlayConnection[] connections = new GooglePlayConnection[] {
    new GooglePlayConnection(/*...*/),
    // ...
};
```